# Create attribute for validation and change the parameter value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I need to get parameter in controller action and validate this parameter. For example:

```
public TestController
{
    public ActionResult TestMethod(int testParamFromUri)
    {
        //here is my validation
        if(testParamFromUri < 0)
        {
            throw new TestException();
        }
        if(testParamFromUri > 50)
        {
            testParamFromUri = 50;
        }

        //other code
    }
}
```

My question:

Is it possible to create attribute where I can do verification like in method above?

and then use this attribute:

```
public ActionResult TestMethod([TestVerification]int testParamFromUri)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the desired behavior as described based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150365/how-to-use-method-parameter-attributes); because there is no good way to access the value for validation.

What you can do is use a Custom [ModelValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidator(v=vs.118).aspx) that will execute any custom validation you would like for a given model.

I couldn't find a good tutorial, but you can get the idea of the basic setup below.

**Controller Code**

```
public TestController
{
    public ActionResult TestMethod(ModelName model)
    {
        //This will be false if your ModelState validator fails.
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

**Model Code**

```
public class ModelName
{
    public int testParamFromUri { get; set; }
}
```

**Model Validator Code**

```
public class ModelNameValidator : IModelValidator<ModelName>
{
    public ModelNameValidator()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelName model)
    {
        //here now my verification
        if(model.testParamFromUri < 0)
        {
            yield return new ModelValidationResult()
            {
                MemberName = "testParamFromUri",
                Message = "Model Error Message Here"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Now, once all of that has been setup, you need to register the model validator so that it executes whenever that ViewModel is used.  This is done in the Global.asax file.

**Global.asax**

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new ModelNameValidator());
```

Also, depending on how complicated your validation is, you could just use a `DataAnnotation` on your newly created model and the `ModelValidator` wouldn't be necessary.

```
public class ModelName
{
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Error Message")]
    public int testParamFromUri { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and detailed example.
maybe I will use your example.